# WebBrowser control and Windows 10 issue (Navigation canceled)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, windows-10

I'm trying to run a WebBrowser containing form on a new STA thread.

The code runs as expected on Windows 7, but on Windows 10 the navigation cancels automatically.

I tried to set each of the zone security settings to minimum from Internet 
Options but nothing changed.

> **Navigation to the webpage was canceled**
>
> Zone: My Computer | Protected
>   Mode: Off res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm#https://google.com/
>
> **This page can’t be displayed**
>
> Zone: My Computer | Protected Mode: Off
>   res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm#https://google.com/

Any suggestions?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;

    var thread = new Thread(ShowFormWebBrowser) {IsBackground = true};
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    thread.Start();
}

public static void ShowFormWebBrowser()
{
    using (var dlg = new FormWebBrowser())
    {
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Resetting the Internet Explorer Settings from Internet Options (Advanced Tab) solved the problem.

Comment: After resetting the IE settings I figured out that I was using a null value string for proxy setting by InternetSetOption command which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although OP had a different issue, for anyone who is still trying to figure this out, For me, it worked after I set `webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;` in my code. Do give it a try.