# WebBrowser does not navigation to Uri

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a `WebBrowser` control in `WinForm`. I am trying to navigate to a web page (for example http://google.com).

```
webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://google.com"));
```

But when when I run it, I see this error:
`Navigation to the webpage was canceled`

I did this before without any problems.

I tried to disable Internet Security and Firewall, still not working!

Comment: Check out the IE options reset found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632315/webbrowser-control-and-windows-10-issue-navigation-canceled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I just Reset Internet Explorer settings from Internet Options (Advanced Tab) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure you just need,

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still trying to figure this out. For me it worked after I set `webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;` Do give it a try.